# Mysql8.0.22 set default value DATE_FORMAT(sysdate() ,'%Y%m%d') error

Tags: mysql, default, date-format, mysql-8.0

Please forgive my poor English
here is my sql

```
create table if not exists `test` (
    `client_id` varchar(18) not null default ' ',
    `begin_date` int not null default DATE_FORMAT(sysdate() ,'%Y%m%d') ,
    `end_date` int not null default DATE_FORMAT(sysdate() ,'%Y%m%d'),
unique index `uk_key` (`client_id` asc)
) engine = InnoDB  default charset = utf8 collate = utf8_bin comment = '';
commit;
```

In 10.3.18-MariaDB-log, there was no error reported  after execution
But In Mysql 8.0.22, the error

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATE_FORMAT(sysdate() ,'%Y%m%d'),
    `end_date` int not nu' at line
```

was reported;

I have modifid the @global.sql_mode and @sql_mode,but it didn`t work.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
```

```
mysql> select @@global.sql_mode;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@global.sql_mode                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**what should i do**

Comment: i want to execute this sql in mysql 8 whitout error, just like in 10.3.18-MariaDB-log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

In particular:

> The default value specified in a DEFAULT clause can be a literal constant or an expression. With one exception, enclose expression default values within parentheses to distinguish them from literal constant default values.

So in MySQL, unlike MariaDB, you need to put an expression inside parentheses when using it as a DEFAULT.

Example:

```
create table if not exists `test` (
    `client_id` varchar(18) not null default ' ',
    `begin_date` int not null default (DATE_FORMAT(sysdate() ,'%Y%m%d')),
    `end_date` int not null default (DATE_FORMAT(sysdate() ,'%Y%m%d')),
unique index `uk_key` (`client_id` asc)
) engine = InnoDB  default charset = utf8 collate = utf8_bin comment = '';
```

Comment: MariaDB has been slowly diverging from MySQL since 2010. It has many differences now, and you should consider it a completely different software product. If you use SQL code on both products, you need to read the SQL reference documentation for both.